# Error: Rotate certificates in Azure Kubernetes Service (AKS)

Tags: azure, kubernetes, azure-aks, x509

I used https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/certificate-rotation this link to rotate certificates in AKS. Certificate got updated but my cluster is in failed state. Because of this my application is down.

I am getting below mentioned error when I am running this command `az aks rotate-certs -g $RESOURCE_GROUP_NAME -n $CLUSTER_NAME`

ERROR: `"error": { "code": "ErrorCodeRotateClusterCertificates", "message": "VMASAgentPoolReconciler retry failed: Category: ClientError; SubCode: OutboundConnFailVMExtensionError; Dependency: Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/extensions; OrginalError: Code=\"VMExtensionProvisioningError\" Message=\"VM has reported a failure when processing extension 'cse-agent-0'. Error message: \\\"Enable failed: failed to execute command: command terminated with exit status=50\\n[stdout]\\n\\n[stderr]\\ncurl: option --proxy-insecure: is unknown\\ncurl: try 'curl --help' or 'curl --manual' for more information\\nCommand exited with non-zero status 2\\n0.00user 0.00system 0:00.00elapsed 100%!!(MISSING)C(string=VMAS agent pools reconciling)PU (0avgtext+0avgdata 7044maxresident)k\\n0inputs+8outputs (0major+372minor)pagefaults 0swaps\\n\\\"\\r\\n\\r\\nMore information on troubleshooting is available at https://aka.ms/VMExtensionCSELinuxTroubleshoot \"; AKSTeam: NodeProvisioning, Retriable: false" } }`

Kubernetes version: 1.14.8
Please help to resolved this issue.

Comment: As suggested in the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/certificate-rotation#rotate-your-cluster-certificates), do the following "It may take up to 30 minutes for az aks rotate-certs to complete. If the command fails before completing, use az aks show to verify the status of the cluster is Certificate Rotating. If the cluster is in a failed state, rerun az aks rotate-certs to rotate your certificates again." If it doesn't help, I suggest reaching out to Azure support.

Answer (score 0):

What version of Ubuntu are you running on your nodes?   From that error, guessing Ubuntu 16.04 or older.

I'm not sure if it will work, but instead of trying to rotate certificates, can you try upgrading the nodes?

You might also want to consider just creating a new cluster, and using VMSS instead of VMAS.